# regular expression to remove custom BB code in PHP

Tags: php, strip

This question is about striping the BB code+contents in PHP.

I have already seen the posts that talk about striping BB code with contents. My question is about a more complicated BB code.

Assume the BB code below:

```
[QUOTE id=123456]a 
b
c
[/QUOTE]
```

Here the [QUOTE] tag has an id and the content is multiline.

What I have tried is the code below but it does not work for multilines:

```
\[(QUOTE).*\](.+?)\[(\/QUOTE)\]
```

My ultimate goal is to strip tags and contents of `[ANYTAG ---]content[/ANYTAG]`. For example if the string is like

```
[T1 id=123]Hi[/T1], How [T2 id=567]are[/T2] you [QuestionMark id=789]?[/QuestionMark]
```

then the output would be `, How you`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this for one BB code snippet in a variable (text), but when you have several it becomes more complicated and you will need to extract the BB codes first, then parse them.

https://3v4l.org/rU2Z5

```
<?php

//One BB Code
$bb = "[QUOTE id=123456 id=654321]a
b
c
[/QUOTE]";

preg_match_all("/\[([a-z]*)/i", $bb, $element);
preg_match_all("/([a-z]*)=/i", $bb, $attribs);
preg_match_all("/=(\w*)/i", $bb, $attribs);
preg_match_all("/\]((.*?\n*\r*)*)\[/i", $bb, $content);

unset($element["0"], $attribs["0"], $content["0"]);

var_dump($element, $attribs, $content);
```